# Phonegap: Calling an action when an app is opened after clicking the home button (iOS)

Tags: ios, events, cordova, onresume

I have an app that's making calls to my server.

When I press the home button and then reopen the app, I'd like it to check the server again.

I've tried the code below but the `onResume` doesn't seem to even run.

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

// Handle the resume event
//
function onResume() {
    // Call to the server
}
```

Comment: don't know cordova, but this is something that would go in the AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:` if that's at all helpful.

Comment: resume is the way to go, if it isn't working it might be a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding success using

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
    // Action when resumed
});
```

and it worked perfectly!